# Swift Scroll View Label Moving After Switching Tab View

Tags: swift, constraints, scrollview, tabbar

I have a tab bar and in one of the views there is a scroll view. I have added a label to this scroll view but upon loading, it isn't in the right spot. After you go to another tab view and return, immidiatly it is in the correct position.

Here is the code:

```
    scrollViewFunc()
    scrollView.addSubview(dateLbl)
    dateLbl.center = CGPoint(x: self.scrollView.center.x, y: self.scrollView.center.y + 100)

    func scrollViewFunc() {

    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    scrollView.contentSize.height = 800
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    //x,w,t,b
    scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

I have put it in the viewDidLoad() to setup the scroll view and also the viewWillAppear but it still has the problem on loading that it is in the incorrect spot.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You assign a frame to your label before the scrollView has a frame.

I.e
    `dateLbl.center = CGPoint(x: self.scrollView.center.x, y: self.scrollView.center.y + 100)`

Should come after

```
    scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Also I wouldn't count on constraints resolving to the correct frame immediately, you probably want to set up dateLbl with constraints as well, or set frames in viewDidLayoutSubviews when you know scrollView has the correct frame.

Comment: But my main problem is that it changes its position when u swutch tab views and then go back. it doesn't load in the correct position the first time @user614273

Comment: "it doesn't load in the correct position the first time"
- This is caused by the ordering. I.e when you assign the CGPoint to the center of dateLbl your scrollView doesn't yet have the correct frame which means `self.scrollView.center.x` and `.y` will have wrong values.

"my main problem is that it changes its position when u swutch tab views and then go back"
- Setting up frames for your subviews in `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of `-viewDidLoad` will ensure that your updates to the frames are made when that tab is tapped.

Comment: Using constraints for the label like
`dateLbl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true` should also resolve your issue as then you would defer the calculation of the labels frame until the scrollView has a frame (handled internally by the constraints engine).